# ArrayList becomes nothing when returning (VBA error 91)

Tags: excel, vba, arraylist

```
Function TasksOnDate(datum As Date, Tasklist As Object) As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Object
Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'Lus over tasklist en voeg Taak toe indien datum tussen start en einddatum ligt
For i = 0 To Tasklist.Count - 1
    If datum >= Tasklist(i).StartDate And datum <= Tasklist(i).EndDate Then
        a.Add Tasklist(i)
    End If
Next i
MsgBox a(1).Title
TasksOnDate = a
End Function
```

Hi Everyone,
My code takes an Arraylist (Tasklist) and a Date as argument
Checking if the date is between the start and enddate of the "Task" Object in the Tasklist.
When they are, they are added to a new Arraylist called a.
The goal is to return a list of all active task on a given date.
However when i try to return the list it appears as nothing.
the messagebox however seems to return the result i was looking for.
When i hover over TasksOnDate it says it is nothing.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

[Messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2nRv.png)[Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lReBN.png)

Comment: Objects require the `set` keyword.

Comment: ^^^^ `Set TasksOnDate = a`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TasksOnDate = a
> ```

The expression that assigns the function's return value is a [*suspicious Let assignment*](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SuspiciousLetAssignment) that [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) flags as such (emphasis mine):

> *Whenever both sides of an assignment without Set are objects, there is an assignment from the default member of the RHS to the one on the LHS. Although this might be intentional, in many situations it will just mask **an erroneously forgotten Set**.*

[image: Rubberduck inspection results]

In other words `TasksOnDate` is declared as an `Object`, and `a` is also an `Object`, but syntactically the expression is a "Let" (value) assignment; this is legal because in VBA/VB6 objects can have a *parameterless default member*, so that expression is in fact assigning to the *default member* of `TasksOnDate`.

Problem is, `TasksOnDate` is `Nothing` (that's normal, it's the reference being assigned!), so accessing its default member throws error 91.

Adding the missing `Set` keyword makes the expression a *reference assignment*, which fixes the problem:

```
Set TasksOnDate = a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Never used rubberduck something to look into :D